# Would Coding a Browser Game in Rails be a Good Idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm lately more and more into Ruby on Rails and i have actually started coding a browser RPG. Do you think it's a good idea to code such a game using a framework like Rails ?

I've tried to do this in PHP in the past, but the workload was amazingly big. On the other hand, doing it with Rails is a hell lot faster.

The question is, though, is performance going to be ok ? What are your thoughts on this ? Would you do something like that in RoR ? Would it scale well ? It's important for me to know if it can be done in a good manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rails to manage users and data and build the game in flash. When HTML5 and javascript catches up I think it might, and that is a maybe for sure, be possible but it's seriously a headache. I think the future will be with node.js and frameworks like rails for managing games but right now its still flash pulling the graphics along.

You want to use the [Midnight Coders](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-rails/overview.html) plugin to connect flash and rails.

Comment: You think that the client side processing is more of a burden ? Maybe rendering is a bit strenuous ? I would mostly worry about database usage and ruby/rails performance to be sincere, but i may be wrong of course.

Comment: Like I said, node.js is going to be the way to go for games but right now it's evolving so fast and it's so new that I don't really know that much about it.

Comment: I did see a few presentations at Google about using node.js for online games instead of flash and it was pretty cool, but I think it's got a long way to go.